# Convert String to Hashmap in Java

Tags: java, regex, hashmap

I have the following string:

```
{id=1111, company=A Sample Company}
```

I want to convert it back to hashmap. I tried the following code below

```
protected HashMap<String,String> convertToStringToHashMap(String text){
    HashMap<String,String> data = new HashMap<String,String>();
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\{\\}\\=\\, ]++");
    String[] split = p.split(text);
    for ( int i=1; i+2 <= split.length; i+=2 ){
        data.put( split[i], split[i+1] );
    }
    return data;
}
```

but the problem is that it can't convert the string with spaces. It outputs something like this:

```
{id=1111, company=A, Sample=Company}
```

I think it has something to do with the regex. Help! Thanks.

Comment: How this string has been generated? By some library? Do you want to convert only this one string or maybe you have a lot similar strings? If yes do they have the same property names?

Comment: Why do you have this string in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will work for you :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "{id=1111, company=A Sample Company}";
    s=s.replaceAll("\\{|\\}", "");
    Map<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String[] entrySetValues = s.split(",");
    for(String str : entrySetValues){
        String[] arr = str.trim().split("=");
        hm.put(arr[0], arr[1]);
    }
    System.out.println(hm);
}

{id=1111, company=A Sample Company}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Guava'a splitter (com.google.common.base.Splitter)
https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/

```
String s = "{id=1111, company=A Sample Company}";
String stringWithoutBracket = s.substring(1, s.length() - 1);
Map<String, String> properties = Splitter.on(",").withKeyValueSeparator("=").split(stringWithoutBracket);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Java Stream:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String value = "{id=1111, company=A Sample Company}";
    Map<String, String> map = Arrays.stream(value.replaceAll("[{}]", " ").split(","))
            .map(s -> s.split("=", 2))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s[0].trim(), s -> s[1].trim()));
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

O/P: `{company=A Sample Company, id=1111}`